# PHP array of functions: interpreter unexpectedly calls all functions during evaluation of the array

Tags: php, arrays, callback

I have this little helper method here:

```
private function continueConv($attribute, $next): void
{
    $sequence = [   $this->askName(),
                    $this->askEmail(),
                    $this->askPhone(),
                    $this->manageMessage()
                ];

    match($attribute) {
        'user_name' => $sequence[0 + (int)$next], 
        'user_email' => $sequence[1 + (int)$next], 
        'user_phone' => $sequence[2 + (int)$next]
    };

    return;
}
```

When the interpreter evaluates the $sequence array, instead of just storing the pointers to those functions, **it calls them all**!
Is this a bug?
Are there working alternatives?
Thanks

---

EDIT:
alternative approach that works:

```
private function continueConv($attribute, $next): void
{

    match($attribute) {
        'user_name' => $next ? $this->askEmail() : $this->askName(), 
        'user_email' => $next ? $this->askPhone() : $this->askEmail(), 
        'user_phone' => $next ? $this->manageMessage() : $this->askPhone()
    };

    return;
}
```

but I'd prefer to use an array of functions in order to easily change the sequence.

---

UPDATE: revised code

```
protected $sequence = [ "run", "askQuestion", "askName", "askEmail", "askPhone", "manageMessage" ];


private function continueConv($fnName, $next): void
{
    $idx = array_search($fnName, $this->sequence) ?: 0;
    $call = [$this, $this->sequence[$idx + (int)$next]]();
}
```

thank you all

Comment: Nope, it's doing what you're telling it to do. Those are function calls, not pointers. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand, aren't they supposed to only get called if I run, for example:
$sequence[0];

Comment: *of course not.* functions are supposed to be called *right where* you called them

Comment: I just need to call the appropriate function, given the current $attribute and the $next boolean.

Comment: what you are looking for is called anonymous functions. which you can store and call later

Comment: ok. So I could make anonymous functions that call my functions..

Comment: Just leave the `()` at `$sequence` definition away, then you store the function pointers. `$sequence[0]();` would call the first one.

Comment: amazing, @MarkusZeller! the anonymous functions are also working, but are uglier. Would you care to post a solution, so that I can approve it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are designing your class this way.  Perhaps we need more context to steer you away from XY Problems; or maybe I am not realizing the beauty of your script.  Why does this not appeal? https://3v4l.org/5oetI @Valentino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array containing the object and method name as a callable. So just put the method names in the array.

```
private function continueConv($attribute, $next): void
{
    $sequence = ['askName', 'askEmail', 'askPhone', 'manageMessage'];

    $func = [$this, match($attribute) {
        'user_name' => $sequence[0 + $next], 
        'user_email' => $sequence[1 + $next], 
        'user_phone' => $sequence[2 + $next]
    }];

    $func();
}
```

Comment: `$func` is a single-use declaration, so it can be safely omitted.  Just whack that `()` after the array's closing `]`.  I don't know if I like the asker's design choice here.  `match()` demands that all branches be spoken for or have a default branch, right?  So this means that the developer will need to be very careful to hardcode all potential outcomes.  I'd probably remove some of the obscurity and create an associative lookup of keys with underscores and method name strings.  Then `$attribute` values can just check the lookup and if the `!method_exists()`, throw an exception.

Comment: @mickmackusa I like to split it into multiple statements to make things clearer, particularly in SO answers. And the assoc array doesn't seem to work here because of the `$next` increment variable,

Comment: Yes, you are right, the `$next` aspect does cause trouble.